# Is UIImageJPEGRepresentation() thread safe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am scaling and cropping a `UIImage` and I want to be able to do it in a block that is thread safe. I could not find in the docs whether `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is thread safe.

In the following code, I crop and scale a `CGImage`, then I create a `UIImage` from that and get the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. The end goal of this block is to get the `NSData*` from the scaled/cropped version.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    CGImageRef imageRef = photo.CGImage;
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    CGContextRef bitmap;

    if (photo.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || photo.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, kFINAL_WIDTH, kFINAL_HEIGHT, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 0, colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);
    } else {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, kFINAL_HEIGHT, kFINAL_WIDTH, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 0, colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);
    }

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, drawRect, imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

    NSData *finalData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref], 1.0);

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.delegate sendNSDataBack:finalData];
    });
});
```

I tried getting the NSData using a CGDataProviderRef, but when I did finally get the NSData, putting it in a UIImage into a UIImageView displayed nothing.

So bottomline question is. Can I do `[UIImage imageWithData:]` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` in another thread in a block using GCD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use UIImageJPEGRepresentation() in the background (I'm using it this way in a current project).

However what you can't do is create a UIImage the way you are doing in the background, the `[UIImage imagewithCGImage]` call must be doing in the main thread (as a rule of thumb all UIKit calls should be done on the main thread).

This seems like a case where you might need nested blocks.

Edit:  My own code I have found does call `[UIImage imagewithCGImage]` while in a background thread, but I am still suspicious that might cause issues in some cases.  But my code does work.

Edit2:  I just noticed you are resizing the image, UIImage+Resize.  There's a very nice class linked to in this post, that has been built to do that in a robust way:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

You should really read that whole page to understand the nuances of resizing images.  As I said, I do use that from a background thread even though part of what it does inside is what you were doing.

Edit3: If you are running on iOS4 or later, you may want to look into using the ImageIO framework to output images, which is more likely to be thread safe:

http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/workingwithimageio.html

Example code for that is hard to find, here's a method that saves a PNG image using ImageIO (based on the code in "Programming With Quartz:2D and PDF graphics in Mac OS X):

```
// You'll need both ImageIO and MobileCoreServices frameworks to have this compile
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

void exportCGImageToPNGFileWithDestination( CGImageRef image, CFURLRef url)
{
    float resolution = 144;
    CFTypeRef keys[2];
    CFTypeRef values[2];
    CFDictionaryRef options = NULL;

    // Create image destination to go into URL, using PNG
    CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL( url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);

    if ( imageDestination == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error creating image destination\n");
        return;
    }

    // Set the keys to be the X and Y resolution of the image
    keys[0] = kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth;
    keys[1] = kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight;

    // Create a number for the DPI value for the image
    values[0] = CFNumberCreate( NULL, kCFNumberFloatType, &resolution );
    values[1] = values[0];

    // Options dictionary for output
    options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL,
                                 (const void **)keys,
                                 (const void **)values,
                                 2,
                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFRelease(values[0]);

    // Adding the image to the destination
    CGImageDestinationAddImage( imageDestination, image, options );
    CFRelease( options );

    // Finalizing writes out the image to the destination
    CGImageDestinationFinalize( imageDestination );
    CFRelease( imageDestination );
}
```

Comment: I noticed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more under method 2 of Resizing an image, he created a UIImage. He then advocates that this is thread safe. I assume based on your response that he is incorrect in that assumption?

Comment: Also, would I need to do dispatch_async back to the main queue, create the UIImage, then dispatch to a global queue for JPEGRep() and then back to the main queue for a callback?

Comment: I am going to have to rescind my original answer - I checked over my own code again, and way in the depths it is calling [UIImage imageWithCGImage] while in the background thread.  So I'm no longer sure that's the issue (since my code seems to be generally working).  Still, you could try creating that on the main queue holding up the background processing until that was done.

Comment: Thank you for adding all that extra information. I actually modified my code from UIImage+Resize. It now both resizes and crops all in the same CGContextDrawImage(). My code does work fine as I suspect that all imageWithCGImage: is basically create an objective-c wrapper around the CGImage. Can you think of any edge case where this might be an issue?

Comment: I can't think of edge cases where this would be an issue, the tricky thing about threading problems is that some are the kind that only show up in rare cases you cannot predict.  So basically just test it very heavily.

Comment: Thank you for your followup and additions. I really appreciate it. Like you said I will test it heavily, but it seems so far that wrapping the UIImage around a CGImage will be ok in an async block.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's official position is that no part of UIKit is thread-safe. However, the rest of your code appears to be Quartz-based, which *is* thread-safe when used in the manner you use it.

You can do everything on a background thread, then do the call to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` back on main:

```
// ...
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    NSData *finalData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref], 1.0);
    [self.delegate sendNSDataBack:finalData];
});

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);
```

Comment: I like the code but I would create the UIImage on the main thread and then return to the background to do the JPEG representation - that's a pretty heavy operation and can really affect UI performance.

Comment: Actually, creating a `UIImage` from a `CGImage` is almost zero expense. `UIImage` just wraps `CGImage`--it doesn't do any heavy lifting itself. And regardless, `UIImage` is part of UIKit and so is not considered thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, creating a UIImage is really cheap - which is why I said it's OK to leave that on the main thread, and should probably be there (actually that call seems to work OK in a background thread and it's probably because of the simplicity).  It's the UIImageJPEGRepresentation() call you have also in the main thread, that is very CPU intensive and can block the UI.  That is what I was saying should be moved into the background.

Comment: Oops, misread. Anyway, the JPEG creator is also part of UIKit and so it's not safe to call it on a worker thread, which is the whole point of the original question. ;)

Comment: I would have thought that as well but it seems to work just fine.  That's really the question at hand, Apple doesn't say if it's thread safe or not but it appears to be, and there is a huge gain from being able to put it in the background.

Comment: "Seems to work" and "thread-safe" are two of the most dangerous phrases to put together in all of CS.

Comment: Yes, I know - and I agree.  However there is some value in experience with things that work, when all else is mystery.  The thing to think about is that UIKit generally is not thread safe because anything interacting with the main drawing context needs to work on the same thread.  But all of the methods under discussion here are working on a context totally removed from the system context, and thinking about how these functions work there is no reason they cannot be thread safe if everything working with a specific context lives in the same thread.  If documentation fails, logic prevails.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but you're also assuming that `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` never does anything that requires the main thread. For all you know, it's implemented by drawing the image into an RGB context and extracting the bytes--an operation which uses other UIKit functionality. It's a cascade effect and you cannot know with certainty that it's thread-safe without seeing the implementation (which you also cannot do.) Erring on the side of caution is something a lot of iPhone "developers" never learn to do.

Comment: I agree you cannot know with certainty but even the other aspects you describe - drawing into another context - would work as long as all the work on that context stayed within the thread.  If it used UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() it simply wouldn't work outright, basically any parts underneath that are dangerous generally do not work at all in a background thread, so knowing that the whole process DOES work in a background thread gives us insight as to how that method works and what it makes use of.  There's no need for it to make an extra context though, it already has the one in the UIImage

Comment: I just noticed in the iOS 4 release notes there is the following line: "Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe." It seems that part of UIKit is now thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is thread-safe because I do the similar things to resize an UIImage, or store image data to database in the background thread. And, the main-thread sometimes is named to UI thread. Anything about updating a screen should be executed on the UI thread. But, the UIImage is an object to store image data. It is not sub-classed from UIView. So, it is thread-safe.

Comment: If Apple don't say it's thread safe then concluding it is empirically is no better than relying on any other undocumented behaviour. There's no reason to assume the implementation of UIImage won't change or to believe you managed to test all internal code paths. That said: Apple did make some of UIKit thread safe fir 4.0, I'm just now unable to find the relevant documentation as to what.

Comment: I agree with @Tommy. Toro do you have any evidence for this?